# navmenu been pushed to left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is the fiddle
http://fiddle.jshell.net/tymvH/2/

im designing a responsive website, i wanted my img to be center when user using the smaller screen resolution. so i code the css as below

```
img.bg {
            min-height: 100%;
            min-width: 1024px;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            position: fixed;            
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
            img.bg {
                left: 50%;
                margin-left: -512px;
            }        
        }
```

but because i pushed the img to left, now my navmenu also been pushed to left. the menu can't show after i clicked on the collapse button.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">      
         <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" data-recalc="false" data-target=".navmenu" data-canvas=".canvas">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
    </div>

<div class="navmenu navmenu-default navmenu-fixed-left">
        <a class="navmenu-brand" href="#">Project name</a>
        <ul class="nav navmenu-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="1.aspx">option 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="2.as[x">Option 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="3.aspx">Option 3</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
```

Comment: PS you also have a typo here: `<li><a href="2.as`[`x">Option 2</a></li>`

Comment: @RenéRoth , fiddle is added. try to resize the browser width and u will know what i meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ditch the media query, use an div with an background instead of an image, remove the fixed min width, set

```
background-size:cover;
background-position:center center;
```

See working [JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/tymvH/4/)

To insert the image from PHP, simply move the background tag to the div style definition:

```
<div style="background-image:url('<?=$imageurl?>');"></div>
```

Comment: image's link will be retrieve from the database. possible to use back  <img> ?